# Executing script file using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, shell, ubuntu

I am creating one .sh file using ECLIPSE on windows machine.

How can I make that same .sh file run on Ubuntu using that same Java code

Answer (score 2):

to run on linux

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("foo.sh");
```

The class java.lang.Runtime features a static method called getRuntime(), which retrieves the current Java Runtime Environment. That is the only way to obtain a reference to the Runtime object. With that reference, you can run external programs by invoking the Runtime class's exec() method.

To execute a .sh script on Windows, you would have to have a suitable command interpreter installed.